# PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd With SQL Alias

Tags: sql-server, powershell, alias, invoke-sqlcmd

It seems to me that Invoke-Sqlcmd does not support the use of SQL Aliases. Is that a true statement?

**Procedure:**

1. Create a SQL Alias (simple example is here: https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-server-alias/)
2. Execute Invoke-Sqlcmd using the alias just created

**Example: If You Added The Port To The Alias When It Was Created**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyTestAlias,1435" -Username "sa" -Password "MyPasswordHere" -Query "Select 123"
```

Result:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Hôte inconnu.)

**Example: No Port Given To The Alias When It Was Created**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyTestAlias" -Username "sa" -Password "MyPasswordHere" -Query "Select 123"
```

**Result**

> Invoke-Sqlcmd: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

SqlCMD seems to work with aliases.
Example:

```
sqlcmd -S MyTestAlias -U sa -P MyPasswordHere -Q "Select 123"
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) for the ServerInstance says,

> For default instances, only specify the computer name: MyComputer. For named instances, use the format ComputerName\InstanceName.

I'm trying to confirm there isn't a workaround for this that would allow invoke-sqlcmd to use Sql Aliases that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Client aliases work just fine for me. Remember that client aliases 1) include ports already, and 2) are separately defined for 32-bit and 64-bit processes. Tested using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` from the `SqlServer` module, version 21.1.18226.

Comment: Also double-check that the alias doesn't have, say, extra whitespace or other typos. See what's in the [registry keys](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50737/4511).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, can you show an example of your invoke-sqlcmd command working with a SQL client alias please?

Comment: Basically the same as yours, `Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyAlias" -Username "sa" -Password "MyPassword" -Query "select getdate();"`. Probably you are running it from a 64-bit PowerShell - that article you linked in the question only shows configuring the 32-bit client aliases.

Comment: In my tests I have actually a 64 bit and 32 bit aliases with the same name. Maybe that's the issue. I'll check.